# jenkins pipeline push string to array

Tags: arrays, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a script in Jenkins:

```
stage('test') {
    steps {
        script {
            def listCatalog = sh script: "ls src/examplecatalog", returnStdout: true
            def arrayExample=[]
            arrayExample+=("$listCatalog")
            echo "${arrayExample}"
        }
    }
}
```

`arrayExample` returned `[catalog_1 catalog_2 catalog_3]` but it's not array I think it's string. I need array like this:
`['catalog_1', 'catalog_2', 'catalog_3']`.

How I can push/append string to empty array in Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sh` Jenkins DSL will return a string, that you have to convert to an array by using split() from groovy [String class api](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) like below

```
node {
    //creating some folder structure for demo
    sh "mkdir -p a/b a/c a/d"
    
    def listOfFolder = sh script: "ls $WORKSPACE/a", returnStdout: true

    def myArray=[]
    listOfFolder.split().each { 
        myArray << it
    }
    
    print myArray
    print myArray.size()
}
```

and the result will be

[image]

In the example, I have used one way to add an element to an array but there are many ways you can add an element to an array like [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#Collections-Lists)

so on your example, it will be

```
stage('test') {
    steps {
        script {
            def listCatalog = sh script: "ls src/examplecatalog", returnStdout: true
            def arrayExample=[]
            listCatalog.split().each {
              arrayExample << it
            }
            echo "${arrayExample}"
        }
    }
}
```